# Is there a workaround for long folder paths in Eclipse Java projects?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, gradle

I have an multi-project Gradle build based on Java code. It's organized into several projects in order to preserve third party dependencies while still allowing for shared code. (There are main() functions in each subcomponent.) Here's my project folder structure on disk, which I believe follows all the Gradle and Java best-practices:

```
    +---repository_for_component
        +---component
        |   +---src
        |       +---main
        |           +---java
        |                +---com
        |                    +---company
        |                        +---product
        |                            +---component
        |                                +---SharedSource.java
        +---subcomponent1
        |   +---src
        |       +---main
        |           +---java
        |                +---com
        |                    +---company
        |                        +---product
        |                            +---component
        |                                +---subcomponent1
        |                                    +---Source1.java
        +---subcomponent2
        |   +---src
        |       +---main
        |           +---java
        |                +---com
        |                    +---company
        |                        +---product
        |                            +---component
        |                                +---subcomponent2
        |                                    +---Source2.java
        +---build.gradle
        +---settings.gradle
        ...
```

One of our devs prefers not to use an IDE (terminal only), and this is understandably a huge pain for him to navigate. It's painful for me too when I have to do anything from the command line or use a file browser.

Because this repository is only for the "component" in question, much of the paths are redundant. In particular, this eliminates 4 redundant folders:

```
    +---repository_for_component
        +---subcomponent1
        |   +---src
        |       +---main
        |           +---java
        |               +---com.company.product.component.subcomponent1
        |                   +---SharedSource.java
    ...
```

It's still a marginal improvement, but it's something. I'd press my luck farther, but while Gradle builds this project just fine, Eclipse gives the error:

> The declared package "com.company.product.component.subcomponent" does not match the expected package ""

Are there any workarounds I can use within Eclipse? Or other suggestions for ways to make this less painful for everyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've confirmed that Eclipse only supports source paths that match the package names; alternatives have been [requested](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16209) and marked as "Won't Fix."

I think I've [found a suitable workaround](https://sampsonlchen.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/three-shortcuts-to-quickly-change-directories-in-linux/) for Linux developers wishing to do their work from the command line. In your `~/.bashrc` file, add something like this:

```
    # Project shortcuts
    export repo="/path/to/repository/"
    alias repo_root="cd $repo"
    alias repo_core="cd $repo/core/src/main/java/com/company/product/component/"
    alias repo_sub1="cd $repo/sub1/src/main/java/com/company/product/component/subcomponent1"
    alias repo_sub2="cd $repo/sub2/src/main/java/com/company/product/component/subcomponent2"
```

Once you have the paths set, start a new terminal instance, and run it like this:

```
    bash-4.1$ repo_root
    bash-4.1$ pwd
    /path/to/repository
    bash-4.1$ repo_sub1
    bash-4.1$ pwd
    /path/to/repository/sub1/src/main/java/com/company/product/component/subcomponent1
```

Alternatively, you could use `export` for each of them instead of aliases. Whatever cans your peaches. The point is that you can quickly traverse those paths much faster and do so from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Remember:  **packages are folders.**

If you have your project broken out into components in that fashion, and you have different packages for each of them, then there at least *should* be a valid reason for that.

While there may be a valid argument to be made on refactoring your components (which I can neither approve of or disapprove of since I don't know how these components should interact with one another), you should not look to flatten the folder structure simply because one or two developers do not wish to use tools to help them navigate it simpler.

The simplest thing to do at this point is to standardize everyone's development environment.  IDEs may not be to everyone's liking, but they specifically help mitigate against pain points like this.

Answer (score 0):

not the perfect answer but it might help. In Eclipse, create a "keyboard shortcut" (Preferences -> General -> Keys) for New (Folder) (e.g. Ctrl + Shift + f) . and it opens new folder dialog instantly.

In Eclipse, create a "keyboard shortcut" (Preferences -> General -> Keys) for New (Folder):
[image: Eclipse]